# How to get Entity Framework dbContext to refresh after Visual Studio restart?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, dbcontext

I can't figure out how to get my DbContext to refresh or re-query the database, even after restarting Visual Studio.

I'm using EF 6.0 database first approach. This means I have an edmx file with a class inheriting from DbContext (MyContext in my case). I instantiate it like any other class - `_myContext = new MyContext();`

The problem is that if I modify data in the database while the program is running the context is never refreshed so it holds on to the stale data. No problem... just stop the program from running and start it up again. Nope, the stale data is still there. After about an hour of stopping and restarting Visual Studio and much debugging it finally realizes the data is stale and refreshes.

My question is 1) how is this possible considering I stopped the program from running? and 2) how can I make sure that every time the application starts it grabs a fresh set of data?

Comment: Are you disposing your context object once you are finished using it ?

Comment: most likely I am not, my context is initialized once in the constructor of my repository and my repository is a singleton which lives for the duration of the application. I don't know where to catch the application stopping so I can dispose of the context.

Comment: `AppDomain.DomainUnload` or `AppDomain.ProcessExit` are two events you can catch to do things when your application is terminating. EDIT: Sorry, DomainUnload is not called in the default domain...

Comment: Can you post some code fragments of how you are creating and using the context in your repository ?

Comment: If you close an application and restart it every object is disposed (also with ASP/MVC but in this case stopping an application is a little bit different). EF is subjected to the same rule. Don't know what is exactly your problem (could be that you are connecting to 2 different database that happens quite often because EF creates and drop databases without saying anything) but for sure if you stop an application every object is disposed.

Comment: Thanks bubi, that's what I thought as well. But my application has been stopped for over 24 hours now and when I start it it is still showing stale data. I'm positive I'm pointing to the correct database and there are no issues with that. If I debug it it will realize the data is stale and it will be refreshed, but it will remain stale until I debug.